# How to create an array in LISP with user input?

Tags: arrays, input, elisp, interactive

I'm learning eLISP for a university course, and I've run into some trouble with a project. I'm trying to write a method that takes a list, and the size, then fills that list with user input. I'm having trouble getting eLISP to actually ask for input -- for some reason or another, the interactive call isn't working. Note that I'm using "Array" instead of "List" because that's how I've written the other 3 scripts, and I'm too confused to change it now.

Here's my code:

```
(defun readArray(anArray size)
  (if (>= size 0)
      (progn
        (setq value 0)
        (princ "Enter values maybe?\n") ;;note this line is executed,so I think the prog is working
        (interactive "\nnEnter a value: ")
        (setq anArray (list value (readArray (- size 1)))))))
```

Running (readArray 4) gives me the output of:

```
Enter values maybe?
Enter values maybe?
Enter values maybe?
Enter values maybe?
Enter values maybe?
(0 (0 (0 (0 ...))))
```

Comment: Lists, not arrays .. anyway, "isn't working" is very descriptive, but you likely need to *do something* with the result.

Comment: Lists, yeah... it's been a long week. Also, what do you mean "do something"?

Comment: What is the `anArray` argument for? You're not using its value.

Comment: To be entirely honest, I don't know how to call it with a blank argument. The course has not been the most... comprehensive. It's a very, very broad introduction.

Comment: The only argument it needs is the size, it will create the result itself and return it.

Comment: What is `tem`? I don't see you setting it anywhere.

Comment: `interactive` is special, it has to be the first thing in the function (after the docstring, if there is one).

Comment: You're printing a prompt, but never reading input. So all you're getting is 0 because that's the value of `value`.

Comment: `tem` would be a typo. Fixed it to value.

Comment: How would I read the input? That's the bit I'm really having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun read-list (size)
  (if (> size 0)
      (let ((value (read-from-minibuffer "Enter value maybe? " nil nil t)))
        (cons value (read-list (- size 1))))))
```

`read-from-minibuffer` prints a prompt and reads a response from the user.